# How can I get an input folder and its files using Javacript for Automator?

Tags: javascript, macos, automator, javascript-automation

I am writing an automator workflow to work with files and folders. I’m writing it in JavaScript as I’m more familiar with it.

I would like to receive a folder, and get the folder’s name as well as the files inside.

Here is roughly what I have tried:

1. Window receives current folders in Finder (I’m only interested in the first and only folder)
2. Get Folder Contents
3. JavaScript:

   ```js
   function run(input,parameters) {
       var files = [];
       for(let file of input) files.push(file.toString().replace(/.*\//,''));
       //  etc
   }
   ```

This works, but I don’t have the folder name. Using this, I get the full path name of each file, which is why I run it through the `replace()` method.

If I omit step 2 above, I get the folder, but I don’t know how to access the contents of the folder.

I can fake the folder by getting the first file and stripping off the file name, but I wonder whether there is a more direct approach to getting both the folder and its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve got it working. In case anybody has a similar question:

```js
//  Window receives current folders in Finder

var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true

function run(input, parameters) {
    let directory = input.toString();
    var directoryItems = app.listFolder(directory, { invisibles: false })
    var files = [];

    for(let file of directoryItems) files.push(file.toString().replace(/.*\//,'')) ;

    //  etc
}
```

I don’t include the Get Folder Contents step, but iterate through the folder using `app.listFolder()` instead. The `replace()` method is to trim off everything up to the last slash, giving the file’s base name.

Comment: Question: If you're familiar with and using JXA what role is Automator playing?